# Cucumber: How to find out either current scenario is last one or not in After hook?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I need to execute specific function after each scenario, except the last one in the queue. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not move the function to be in the Before hook instead?
That way it would never run on the last scenario, but would run for all other scenarios.

If you don't want it to run before the first scenario for whatever reason, you can set a global variable to store whether this scenario is the first one.

e.g.

In env or somewhere create and set

```
$first_scenario = true
```

Then in the before hook

```
run_your_function unless $first_scenario
$first_scenario = false
```